# Draw vertical line when two lines cross in Highcharts

Tags: javascript, jquery, highcharts

I have a temperature line graph, and I want to draw a red vertical line when the two temperatures (surface temp and dew point) cross. So far what I do is I draw a vertical rectangle on top of my graph at places I calculated it crosses.

It works correctly, but there are a few downsides to this :

- The line kind of stands out of the graph ... we can tell I added it later and not in the graph itself;
- The pixels are hardcoded, if I change the graph width it might not be good (I could probably fix this, but still)
- I would like a little tooltip when I highlight a line, but since it's a simple rectangle, it just sits there and is not dynamic at all.

What would be my best option to integrate this line better un my graphs?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

plotLines are your best way to draw the line - http://api.highcharts.com/highcharts#xAxis.plotLines

Two things:

1) The difficult part will be calculating where the lines cross. if they do not cross at a data point, which they most likely won't, there will need to be some guesswork involved, as there is no value you can retrieve from the chart to tell you the axis value where they cross.

2) if you are using separate y axes for these two series, which I assume you must be since they are completely different units and scales, then the point where the lines cross will be COMPLETELY arbitrary and meaningless, as where they cross will be strictly a matter of how the scaling for each axis is set up, and the values have no actual correlation to each other.